# No HDMI output -Ubuntu 19.04 - Nvidia Graphic card

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Gygabyte Sabre 15 gaming laptop with a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050. The graphic pilot installed is the 418.56.

When I plug a monitor through hdmi (there is no VGA port), it is not detected. The xrandr output look like this concerning the hdmi:

```
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have tried number of 'solutions' found on this platform or elsewhere : switching to gdm, switching on the intel graphic card, reinstalling nvidia driver,... nothing worked so far.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/UEFI Settings for a config option to enable/disable the HDMI port?  Sometimes additional ports are only available when the Nvidia hardware is selected (vs integrated).

Comment: Hi @ubfan1 Yes I did. There is no such thing in my BIOS option.

Comment: Just checking have you adjusted the Displays menu?

Comment: Hi @BJsgoodlife what do you mean? The second monitor doesn't appear in the display menu.

Comment: OK then that is not the issue, my apologies.